# Trouble installing Xcode: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'

Tags: xcode, macos

I am using macOS Catalina (10.15). I want to install Xcode, but having trouble.

When I type following in the terminal, I get an error.

```
$ xcode-select --install

xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

But when I type the following, I get this error:

```
$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'
```

Comment: Well, `xcode-select --install` does not install Xcode. And `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` doesn't install it either. So I wouldn't expect that to work, eh. To install Xcode, _download_ it, yourself, and put it in the Applications folder, yourself.

Comment: There is a blue cloud icon with a down arrow on each app page to download and install. Xcode app: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835

Answer (score 4):

I was new to MacOS when I encountered this issue too.

To install Xcode we have two ways: [Web](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) and App Store on your Mac. If you download it using App Store the application will be present in the Applications Folder. For Web, a .xip is downloaded at your Download location by default Downloads Folder, which you need to click for the extraction to take place. Once the extraction happens, a Xcode Application will appear in the same location. Double click on the Application for it to install and then place the Application in the Applications Folder for it to appear in the Applications.

Now you will need to set the path for Command Line to be able to use Xcode commands.

**sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer** if you are using the Beta Version

or else

**sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer**

Note: Check your Xcode Application and use that in the path:

**/Applications/Xcode Application Name.app/Contents/Developer**

Answer (score 0):

If Xcode was downloaded from [apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode) Xcode.app/Contents/Developer cannot be there. That's a Developer command line tools install you must have got all Dev binaries under CLI pkg:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/
```